# angular only set required if button is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

How to set required field in angular if only button is clicked. My current one is that the error is already showing without the user typing or clicking the button.

What I want is that the red error "folder name is required" should only pop-up if when the user click the submit button and the field is empty. Any idea guys ? Thanks.

```
private _createModelForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      propertyId: this.data.propertyId,
      folderName: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+.?/)
      ]),
      documentManagementFolderId:this.data.documentManagementFolderId
    });
  }




<mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('folderName').hasError('pattern')">
                    Folder name must not include special characters.
                </mat-error>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share full html code snipped used in create folder ui?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `dirty` and `touched` properties too

something like:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="(modelForm.get('folderName').dirty || modelForm.get('folderName').touched) && modelForm.get('folderName').hasError('pattern')">
                    Folder name must not include special characters.
                </mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [{updateOn:'submit'}](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#optimizing-performance-of-async-validators) but you need paid atention and how you create the formGroup

There're **two differents** ways to create a FromGroup

1.-Using the constructor -you use new FormGroup and new FormControl- (see that you don't use formBuilder in any place but you need use new FormControl with each control, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls)

```
return new FormGroup({
      propertyId: new FormControl(this.data.propertyId), //<--each property
                                                         // is a new FormControl
      folderName: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+.?/)
      ]),
      documentManagementFolderId:new FormControl(this.data.documentManagementFolderId)
    },{updateOn:'submit'});
```

2.-Using formBuilder -but see that in this case you never use new FormControl or new FormArray, if you want to create a nested formGroup or a formArray use this.formBuilder.group and this.formBuilder.array, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls)

```
return this.formBuilder.group({
      propertyId: this.data.propertyId,
      folderName: ['', [              //<--see that is not new FormControl
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+.?/)
      ]],
      documentManagementFolderId:this.data.documentManagementFolderId
    },{updateOn:'submit'});
```

(*)NOTE: I use updateOn in the whole form, you can also use only in a FormControl.

Answer (score 0):

basically @robert' answer is correct, I'd like to offer u another way if u really want to dispaly the message only after clicking the button

- declare a variable name `submitted = false` in your component
- set `submitted = true` in your submit function

then in the html file

```
<mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('folderName').hasError('pattern') && submitted">
   Folder name must not include special characters.
</mat-error>
```

Comment: You can access `submitted` from the template [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rvfdkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

I would do it programmatically like this

```
buttonOnClick() {
    const fc = this.modelForm.get('folderName')
    fc.setValidator([Validator.required, <any old validators here>])
    fc.updateValueAndValidity()
}
```

Also, default empty value should be `null` and not `''` if I'm correct