# why formgroup is not detecting changes on select element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

For some reason, change is not detected on the select element in Angular reactive form. Below is the code extract

Component html code

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="postProjectForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Job Type:</label>
                            <select formControlName="jobType" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" >
                                <option *ngFor="let jt of jobTypes" [value]="jt">{{jt}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>                   
</form>
```

Component js code

```
jobTypes = ['Full time', 'Part time', 'Intership', 'Freelancing'];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
this.postProjectForm = this.fb.group({jobType: new FormControl(this.jobTypes[0])})
}

onSubmit() {
console.log(this.postProjectForm.get('jobType').value);
}

 onChange(val){
        console.log(val);
 }
```

The code starts fine, i.e. the select is populated with three four values with 'Full Time' as default value. However, when I change the option and submit, the onSubmit method logs the initial value ( Full Time ).
Also the onChange method does not fire at all!

Comment: that doesn't help. moreover this.postProjectForm.controls.jobType.pristine is still showing true inside onSubmit, even when I change the select value and submit

Comment: `this.fb.group({jobType: this.jobTypes[0]})`. If you use formBuilder **not** use new FormControl, see,e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470645/angular-only-set-required-if-button-is-clicked/68474549#68474549

Comment: still the same, for some reasons its working in other pages/components

Answer (score -1):

Try updating: `<select formControlName="jobType" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" >`
to `<select formControlName="jobType" (change)="onChange($event.target)" >`

and `onChange(val){ console.log(val); }` to `onChange(val){ console.log(val.value); }` and see if the onChange event now works. If this works, then the form should also work. I don't see any other reason why it won't.

If so, I can probably explain what's happening.

Comment: strict type checking is off so I guess that is that the issue. However everything is working fine in other pages/components